# How to change the color of an SVG circle fill color using jQuery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the color of a circle of an SVG element dynamically. How to change the color of a circle dynamically according to the value getting from the AJAX call response?

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td style="width: 33.3333%; text-align: center;">
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle id="parking_slot" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      format: 'json'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.field1 < 50) {
        $("#field1").text("car is parked");
        $("#parking_slot").fill("red");
      } else {
        $("#field1").text("car is not parked");
        $("#parking_slot").fill("green");
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      $('#errors').text("There was an error processing your request. Please try again.");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Dunno about jquery, yet in javascript there are two ways: `setAttributeNS()` and `style.fill`.

Comment: with the attr method `$("#parking_slot").attr('fill', 'hotpink')`

Comment: got answer -   $('#parking_slot').css({ fill: "red" });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
$("#parking_slot").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Thank you Krishna for accepting my answer. Can you please vote it up? Thank you very much in advance.